# Getting the length of an array of undetermined size at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just messing around with Compiler Explorer a bit... I was asking myself why there is no lenth() function in C++ to determine the size of an array at compile time, because in my opinion it should be easy to write. But apparently it's not that easy. My idea was something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_all(const int num[], const size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << num[i] << endl;
}

template <class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t  length(T (&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    print_all(a, length(a));
}
```

However, according to godbolt.org with clang 11.0.1, x86-64, this will be compiled into the following:

```
main:                                   # @main
        ...
        call    unsigned long length<int const, 4ul>(int const (&) [4ul])
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 24]       # 8-byte Reload
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    print_all(int const*, unsigned long)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbp
        ret
unsigned long length<int const, 4ul>(int const (&) [4ul]):             # @unsigned long length<int const, 4ul>(int const (&) [4ul])
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     eax, 4
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

So it's not inlined.

Is there a way to get a convenience function with zero runtime cost?

PS: I am not interested in this because I actually want to use such a function. I know that `std::array` or `std::span` would be way better solutions in almost all cases and that the raw loop in `print_all` is fishy etc. I am asking this because I want to improve my understanding of C++ and because arrays of undetermined size occur 'in the wild.'
Also I am aware that I could use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`, but I was thinking that there should be a way to get things like this done using templates and `constexpr` because that's somehow what they are for (creating convenience that can be paid for at compile time).

Comment: Can't see any call to such function when [optimisations are enabled](https://godbolt.org/z/GYb7e6drE)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! My bad. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `std::size(a)` which does exactly the same thing as your `length(a)`, so it's not that bad of an idea. As others have said, the function call will be removed if you enable optimizations.

Also you can do `std::extent_v<decltype(a)>`, which should compile to nothing even without optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out in the comments, enabling optimisations does remove the call. Alternatively, you could use C++ attributes; with GCC and clang inserting `[[gnu::always_inline]]` will always omit the call:

```c
template <class T, size_t N>
[[gnu::always_inline]] constexpr size_t  length(T (&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Other compilers have [different ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-160#inline-__inline-and-__forceinline) of forcing this behaviour.